# Solapamiento div modal-footer modal-body

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-3

He creado un `modal` con una serie de `checkbox` que se crean diatónicamente con `angularjs` y `bootstrap 3`. El problema que tengo es que se solapa el `modal-footer` y el `modal-body`. Lo podéis ver [aquí](https://plnkr.co/edit/tQak1ch8ixfJcS2N?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {

  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance =  $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
      controller: "ModalContentCtrl",
      size: '',
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(response){
        $scope.result = `${response} button hitted`;
    });

  };
})

app.controller('ModalContentCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.title = 'Columnas';
    $scope.body = 'Seleccionar columnas para el informe';
  $scope.columns = [
                {'name': 'Fecha', selected: true},
                {'name': 'Programa', selected: true},
                {'name': 'Asistencia', selected: true},
                {'name': 'Comentarios', selected: true},
                {'name': 'Fecha creación', selected: true},
                {'name': 'Usuario', selected: true},
            ];
  $scope.ok = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  }

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  } 

});
```

Comment: Agrega dentro de la clase `.modal-body` la propiedad `overflow-y: auto;` y nos cuentas cómo te va con eso.

Comment: Perfecto, eso era. Gracias